# Flag transactions that happened after a certain limit in a specific time window (SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, dataframe, analytics, amazon-athena

Im trying to figure out a way to solve this problem:
I am working with a data table, with many sales records and its timestamp (saving when it happened). Also, I have some rules that flags sales that exceeds a certain limit of sales within a time interval.
Eg: I want to know cases when 4 sales were made within 1 minute. So I would like to flag the sales that happened in that 1 minute window if this number is equal or higher than 4. If 7 sales were made at
1:00:01, 1:00:10, 1:00:20, 1:00:30, 1:00:40, 1:00:50 and 1:01:30, I'd like to flag the first six sales records, because considering each of them individually, we can find more than 4 sales within 1 minute from that timestamp.
On the other hand, considering 3 sales that happened at 1:00:00, 1:01:00, 02:00:00, none of them should be flagged.

Any tips on how to solve it?
Here is a data example and the desired output:

[image]

If we consider each timestamp of the sales marked as blue, we can find more than 4 sales in a 1 minute time window from it.
The goal here is to create alerts to the store that sells too many products in a short period of time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share some examples of data, desired output and query you have tried.

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated my previous post with some data simulated example. I haven't created any query so far, cause I'm struggling with that dynamic time window